# How to get the current Path on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, path

I have a file with shaders inside, in my Qt project file.

When i tried to get the Path of the application

```
QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()
```

It give me :

> "C:/Users/USER_NAME/Desktop/PROJECT_NAME/build-PROJECT_NAME-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug"

But actually, the shaders files are in :

> "C:/Users/USER_NAME/Desktop/PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/shaders"

How can i get the correct path ?

Comment: I don't know what a "file with shaders on it" is, but smells like a good candidate for using the [resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the correct results. By default most IDEs, Qt Creator included, compile the project to a different directory than the sources are stored in and run it from there or from yet another location.

Assuming you're using Qt Creator, you can change the working directory of the executable in project settings pane:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

As per `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` which returns the directory that contains the application executable. The output you're getting is based on while you're running your application from the Qt IDE. And, it expects your shaders files to be under the same location as your executable. So, either you can use a common location (like. %appdata%) or use hard coded path where your shader files are located. Another solution might be copy your shader files under the location of executable, in your case:

`C:/Users/USER_NAME/Desktop/PROJECT_NAME/build-PROJECT_NAME-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug`